# Writing a TCP server in bash

Tags: bash, tcp

So, I recently found out about how you can send TCP packets through the `/dev/tcp/hostname/port` file, but my main problem here is how I receive them. I want to make a bash script that can host a TCP server, and another script as a TCP client. Some help would be great. I would also like to note that I am doing this as a learning experience, which is why I'm not using `ssh` or `telnet` as a way to preform the tasks I want.

Comment: @Mikel Nothing really. I honestly have no idea what im doing, and I was going to piece together the information I got.

Comment: What's wrong with `cat </dev/tcp/hostname/port` (for instance to output to the console)? If that's not what you want please add more details about what exactly you need.

Comment: I don't think bash gives a syntax to listen on ports. Use netcat.

Comment: TCP doesn't do packets either, but *streams*.

Answer (score 8):

According to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/49947/52934), no. You can't do it because `bash` doesn't attempt to [`bind(2)`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=bind&sektion=2) the sockets,  but rather only attempts to [`connect(2)`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?connect).

Here are a few ways you might start a `netcat` server:

*(I use [`nmap`'s `ncat`](https://nmap.org/ncat/) because the [GNU `nc`](http://netcat.sourceforge.net/) hasn't seen an update since 2004)*

---

```
local $ :|{  ncat -l 9999 --keep-open --allow localhost |
local >      PS1='ncat $ '  PS2='ncat > ' dash +m -i 2>&1
local >   }  1<>/dev/fd/0
[1] + Running  : | { ncat -l 9999 --keep-open --allow localhost | PS1='ncat $ ' PS2='ncat > ' dash +m -i 2>&1; } 1<>/dev/fd/0
```

---

I borrow the `:|` pipe at the end there - `dash` writes out to it, and `ncat` reads it because the `:` null command certainly has no need of it. It's sometimes easier than `mkfifo`.

Anyway, the point is that everything `ncat` writes is piped to `dash`'s standard input, and everything `dash` writes is piped to `ncat`'s standard input. It's not `bash`, I know, but I'll get to that. Note though, at least, the `+m` option.

---

```
local $ ncat localhost 9999
ncat $ echo $0 $$
dash 31231
ncat $ ls -l /dev/fd/[012]
lr-x------ 1 mikeserv mikeserv 64 Dec 11 23:28 /dev/fd/0 -> pipe:[3563412]
l-wx------ 1 mikeserv mikeserv 64 Dec 11 23:28 /dev/fd/1 -> pipe:[3567682]
l-wx------ 1 mikeserv mikeserv 64 Dec 11 23:28 /dev/fd/2 -> pipe:[3567682]
ncat $ ^C
local $
```

---

I have to use the `+m` because a `-m`onitored job-controlled shell - as is generally set to on by default for an `-i`nteractive shell - would try to read from its controlling terminal and it would be sent a `SIGTTIN` - which would automatically suspend it by default, or else *(if it were trying to ignore or block it)* kill it.

---

```
[1] + Stopped(SIGTTIN) : | { ncat -l 9999 | dash -i 2>&1; } 1<>/dev/fd/0
```

---

But there is no terminal here - these are just pipes, as you can see in the `ls` output - and so `-m`onitoring is a no-go.

`bash`, as it happens, doesn't seem to be as flexible about its initial interactive terminal associations, even with `readline` disabled.

---

```
[1] + Stopped(SIGTTIN) : | { ncat -l 9999 | bash --noediting +m -i 2>&1 ; } 1<>/dev/fd/0
```

---

So what to do? Well, we need a pseudo-terminal. Something like what we have in the emulator.

---

```
local $ ls -l /dev/fd/[012]
lrwx------ 1 mikeserv mikeserv 64 Dec 11 23:30 /dev/fd/0 -> /dev/pts/0
lrwx------ 1 mikeserv mikeserv 64 Dec 11 23:30 /dev/fd/1 -> /dev/pts/0
lrwx------ 1 mikeserv mikeserv 64 Dec 11 23:30 /dev/fd/2 -> /dev/pts/0
```

---

We can get one from the `/dev/ptmx` master-device on a linux system *(though your user will probably need to be a member of the `tty` group if you don't want to `chown` it first)*. If we `<` [`open(2)`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=open&sektion=2) the ptmx device a new pseudo-terminal will be created, and if we afterwards [`unlockpt(3)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/unlockpt.html) the new device file, we can read and write it.

Some time ago I learned there isn't really a simple way to do so with the shell, and so [I wrote a little C program for it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/179030/52934). You'll find some explanation and simple build instructions *(actually just a copy/paste into a shell prompt)* at that link - it's the `pts` program I use below.

---

```
local $ { 9>&- setsid -c -- bash <> "$({ pts && 
local >   >&9  ncat -l 9999 -k --allow localhost
local > } <&9  &)" 2>&0 >&2 ; } 9<> /dev/ptmx
local $
```

---

There a `bash` is started as *session leader* on the pseudo-terminal which `pts` unlocks and names to its standard out - which is substituted for the `<>` standard in redirection for `bash`. Nothing apparently happens, though, because all of the i/o is going elsewhere - to the new pseudo-terminal - and the only link is the `ncat` server started on port 9999. The `-i`nteractive switch isn't necessary here - `bash` will automatically be interactive on its own pty.

---

```
local $ ncat localhost 9999
[mikeserv@desktop ~]$ echo hey
echo hey
hey
[mikeserv@desktop ~]$ ls -l /dev/fd/[012]
ls -l /dev/fd/[012]
lrwx------ 1 mikeserv mikeserv 64 Dec 12 00:27 /dev/fd/0 -> /dev/pts/4
lrwx------ 1 mikeserv mikeserv 64 Dec 12 00:27 /dev/fd/1 -> /dev/pts/4
lrwx------ 1 mikeserv mikeserv 64 Dec 12 00:27 /dev/fd/2 -> /dev/pts/4
[mikeserv@desktop ~]$ ^[[A^[[A
```

---

Well, we're nearly there. So we've definitely got a socketized-`bash`, but probably you notice the weird double-echo there, and the funny escapes at the last prompt are actually me pressing the ^up arrow key. The problem here is we have two levels of pseudo-terminals - the one on which my `ncat` client runs is set to `stty echo` the same as the one on which the server runs. And because the client-side terminal is line-oriented, and flushes output once per input newline, and is also printing ctrl-char escapes according to the default `stty echoctl` setting, the `bash` never receives the ^up arrow key at all, and we only see the funny little escapes.

Ok. We can handle that too.

---

```
local $ ncatsh()(
local >    ${2+":"} set  localhost "${1:?ncatsh(): No port number provided!}"
local >    stty="   stty -F'$(tty)'" || unset stty
local >    trap " ${stty- ncat '${1##*\'*}' '${2##*\'*}' </dev/null} \
local >           ${stty+$(for a in -g 'raw -echo isig intr "^A" quit "" susp ""'
local >                    do  eval "$stty $a";done)}
local >             trap - 0 1 2; exit"    0 1 2
local >    ncat  "$@"
local > )
```

---

That function will check if its standard in is a terminal - your local terminal - and if not will just pass-through input to an `ncat` client. But if so it will `trap` the *EXIT*, *HANGUP*, and *INTERRUPT* signals to restore the terminal state on its standard in when it quits. This is a good thing, because it also *alters* that state before calling `ncat` on standard in.

The local echo is disabled and the local terminal is otherwise set to *raw* mode - so each keypress is sent to the `ncat` server immediately. In fact, all special local-mode keys are disabled *except* the local *intr* - which is usually *`CTRL+C`*, but is here configured for *`CTRL+A`* instead - because *`CTRL+C`* will be interpreted by the `bash` server.

I'll do `ls` again but just by pressing ^up arrow then *`RETURN`*.

---

```
local $ ncatsh 9999

[mikeserv@desktop ~]$ ls -l /dev/fd/[012]
lrwx------ 1 mikeserv mikeserv 64 Dec 12 01:00 /dev/fd/0 -> /dev/pts/4
lrwx------ 1 mikeserv mikeserv 64 Dec 12 01:00 /dev/fd/1 -> /dev/pts/4
lrwx------ 1 mikeserv mikeserv 64 Dec 12 01:00 /dev/fd/2 -> /dev/pts/4
[mikeserv@desktop ~]$ ^C
[mikeserv@desktop ~]$ ^C
[mikeserv@desktop ~]$ ^C
[mikeserv@desktop ~]$
local $
```

---

You can't see it there because the local echo is disabled when it is pressed, but I pressed *`CTRL+A`* to interrupt the session and come back to the local prompt, at which time all of the local terminal configuration is restored to rights. The `bash` server remains, though, and `ncatsh 9999` will take me right back if I will it.

Comment: Whoa. I'm not that advanced yet. It's kinda stupid that no one has really made a tool for what I'm describing, besides game servers.

Comment: I must hereby ignore the add-comment tooltip and offer you my wholehearted ***thanks*** for these gems. I just stumbled on this (while doublechecking if bash's /dev/tcp can bind()) and learned like fifty new things. I love working with the shell, this is great! Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

To ease your job, try using the "netcat" tool. It may be used as server or client, and is able to send and receive arbitrary data.

No need to bother with low-level stuff then..

```
#server listening on port 8000/tcp
$>netcat -l 8000

#client sending stuff to localhost 8000/tcp
$>netcat localhost 8000
blah
```

Comment: Thats good, but my problem lies within netcat, which is why I wanted to do stuff over TCP. If you can help me with netcat, that would be nice too. I want to have a nc server echo back data when I send a command. for example, `CMD> ls`, and then the computer I'm connected to will run `ls`, send the data over to the nc client, then wait for another command. I tried doing this in a bash script, but I couldn't figure out how to send and recieve data over nc at the same time without disconnecting and reconnecting.

Comment: You just described `telnet`.  You should use `telnet`, or use `ssh` if you want a secure connection.

Comment: @MyNameIsBoring Yes, I use `ssh`, but one of the goals (which I should edit in) was to make my own kind of remote connection program as a learning experience. I haven't used `telnet` that much, mostly because of how weird it is to use, in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

`bash`'s virtual `/dev/tcp/host/port` files (a ksh feature initially) can only be used to *connect* a socket to a TCP port.

If you want to do more, like creating a listening socket and spawning accepting sockets from that, that can't be done with redirection.

`zsh` has support for that via its `zsh/net/tcp` module and `ztcp` builtin.

```
zmodload zsh/net/tcp
handle-connection() (
  IFS= read -ru4 line || exit
  print -r "Got: $line"
  print -ru4 "Hello $line"
  ztcp -c 4
)

ztcp -l -d 3 1234 # create a TCP listening socket on port 1234 on fd 3
while ztcp -ad4 3 # accept connection on fd 4
do handle-connection & exec 4>&-
done
```

It's still limited in that you can't specify which address to bind on or the size of the listen queue, or shutdown only one direction, or set socket options... It also doesn't do UDP or SCTP (you can do Unix domain sockets though with the `zsocket` command).

If you want anything fancier or if you don't have zsh, you could use `socat`. For instance, here with `bash` exported functions:

```
handle_connection() {
  IFS= read -r line &&
    printf 'Hello %s\n' "$line"
}
export -f handle_connection
socat tcp-listen:1234,reuseaddr,fork 'exec:bash -c handle_connection'
```

With `socat`, the possibilities are endless, see the man page for details.

For instance, for the server to spawn a shell session:

```
socat tcp-listen:1234,reuseaddr,fork exec:bash,pty,ctty,setsid,stderr,sane
```

On the client side, you'd connect as:

```
socat -,raw,echo=0 tcp:host:1234
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to create your own `xinetd` service like this:

`/etc/services`:

```
...
foo             500/tcp
...
```

`/etc/xinetd.d/foo`:

```
service foo
{
        disable         = no
        bind            = 127.0.0.1
        socket_type     = stream
        protocol        = tcp
        log_on_failure += USERID
        server          = /usr/local/lib/foo.sh
        user            = il
        instances       = UNLIMITED
        wait            = no
        log_on_success  =
}
```

`/usr/local/lib/foo.sh`:

```
read ...
...
echo ...
```

Thus your shell script gets executed for each client connection with stdin/stdout attached directly to the socket.